# Different Piano Octaves

Tags: piano, notation, ottava

What comes after 8va and 15ma in Piano music?  I have tried searching, but nothing helpful comes up.

Answer (score 8):

Well, *purely theoretically*, a three-octave transposition would be *22ma*.  A four-octave transposition would be *29ma*.  You just keep adding 7 to each previous number.

However, **don't use these**.  No one except true music nerds will be able to puzzle out what you mean.  **It's not standard music notation.**  I've never seen an example of this, and even *15ma* is exceptionally rare, to the point that many musicians wouldn't know what it means.  (However, an internet search tells me, weirdly, that [some music fonts](https://www.w3.org/2019/03/smufl13/tables/octaves.html) include glyphs for *22ma* or even *22mb*!)

For piano, either **use ledger lines or change clef instead**.

The only utility I can think of potentially for these symbols might be in inserting cue notes for an instrument in a wildly different range and refusing to change clef.  (But cue notes frequently don't notate correct octave anyway, so this sort of thing simply isn't necessary.)

Comment: Musescore has 22ma lines in the same section as 15ma lines (if you care to use them).

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing after 15ma. You'll just have to bite the bullet and draw a ledger line or two. A note on the second ledger line, marked 15ma, is the top C on a grand piano so you shouldn't need to write notes higher than that unless you're transcribing bats.

Comment: maybe the OP is in possession of a Imperial Bösendorfer

Answer (score 4):

Nothing.   Look at my piano (it's a slightly short one, the full 88 notes would reach C).

And look at the notation.  Section A doesn't require an 8va line.  B and C are 8va and 15ma.   There is no section D. None is needed,  There's no more piano :-)

[image]

Comment: Unless you are fortunate enough to have one of those Bosendorfers, with the 'hidden' extra low octave...

Comment: @Laurence Payne Nice pic. Yamaha? I envy you that long stand. And the Leroy Anderson! What's in it?

Comment: Bechstein.   Don't envy the long stand, make one like I did!  Simple bit of woodwork.

Comment: Yep, but in these days of digital pianos,  not all that difficult to pitch-shift the whole dang thing a couple octaves :-)

Comment: @Tim: Even if you do have one of those extended pianos, *15ma bassa* is plenty to notate all of the notes in that octave, with just a couple ledger lines.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - simplicity itself, on some. However, how would one then play something low with l.h. and several octaves higher with r.h. The whole dang thing shifts! And usually it's not needed on 88s; on 61s and 76s there's the problem.

Comment: iDK may come in handy when playing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ithskt49HA

Comment: @LaurencePayne Bechstein? Lovely. These hands are wholly untutored in woodwork. I'll stick with Sellotape. Literally.

Comment: Lovely, but not THAT lovely.  These were budget Bechsteins  marked in Britain in the first half of the 20th century.  Not overstrung and a rather noisy action.   A nice house piano though.

Answer (score 2):

I found this use of 29ma in this Keyboard book from the musical Spamalot. When playing multiple MIDI instruments, it's sometimes necessary to pre-program octaves when you simply don't have enough hands! Thought it would be interesting anyway.

[image: Extract from 'Knights of the Round Table - Keyboard 3 - Spamalot]

Comment: That’s a really good find!